# Disable volume up button to capture photos in UIImagePickerView?

Tags: iphone, camera, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there anyway to disable photo capture with the volume button on `UIImagePickerController` in iOS 5?

Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it. `:)`

Comment: Perhaps you could look into delegate methods on device buttons like the volume buttons?

Comment: @AlexsanderAkers Hey Alexsander, Thank you so much for replying! I was wondering, do delegate methods on device buttons as you said above exist? Are they documented? Please Please Respond, and Thanks a lot again!

Comment: `UIApplication` has a `-beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents` method but I looked into the control event types and *volume up* doesn't seem to be one of them…

Comment: @AlexsanderAkers , Well, in my application I have an `UIImagePickerController`. I show my camera buttons, `imagePicker.showsCameraControls = YES` just because I want to be able to zoom... I tried to use custom zoom in overlay but the processing of the new image was too slow... Do you have any idea of how to apply `cameraViewTransform` so it works fast? Or do you have any idea of how to be able to know when the 'Preview' screen appeared after the camera captured a photo? Should I make my own delegate? Thank you so much for your time! I REALLY REALLY Appreciate it!! `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No. You can't.**

You can't access the volume control buttons by using delegate methods unless you use Private API's. If you use private API's for this your app will get rejected.

From Apple documentation,

> 10.5
>        Apps that alter the functions of standard switches, such as the Volume Up/Down and Ring/Silent switches, will be rejected